# catching signals while reading from pipe with select()

Tags: c, signals, pipe, signal-handling

[using select() with pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950499/using-select-with-pipe) - this is what I am doing and now I need to catch `SIGTERM` on that. how can I do it? Do I have to do it when `select()` returns error ( < 0 ) ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, `SIGTERM` will **kill** your process if not caught, and `select()` will *not* return. Thus, you must install a signal handler for `SIGTERM`. Do that using `sigaction()`.

However, the `SIGTERM` signal can arrive at a moment where your thread is *not* blocked at `select()`. It would be a rare condition, if your process is mostly sleeping on the file descriptors, but it can otherwise happen. This means that either your signal handler must do something to inform the main routine of the interruption, namely, setting some flag variable (of type `sig_atomic_t`), or you must guarantee that `SIGTERM` is only delivered when the process is sleeping on `select()`.

I'll go with the latter approach, since it's simpler, albeit less flexible (see end of the post).

So, you block `SIGTERM` just before calling `select()`, and reblock it right away after the function returns, so that your process only receives the signal while sleeping inside `select()`. But note that this actually creates a race condition. If the signal arrives just after the unblock, but just before `select()` is called, the system call will not have been called yet and thus it will not return `-1`. If the signal arrives just after `select()` returns successfully, but just before the re-block, you have also lost the signal.

Thus, you must use `pselect()` for that. It does the blocking/unblocking around `select()` atomically.

First, block `SIGTERM` using `sigprocmask()` before entering the `pselect()` loop. After that, just call `pselect()` with the original mask returned by `sigprocmask()`. This way you guarantee your process will only be interrupted while sleeping on `select()`.

In summary:

1. Install a handler for `SIGTERM` (that does nothing);
2. Before entering the `pselect()` loop, block `SIGTERM` using `sigprocmask()`;
3. Call `pselect()` with the old signal mask returned by `sigprocmask()`;
4. Inside the `pselect()` loop, now you can check safely whether `pselect()` returned `-1` *and* `errno` is `EINTR`.

Please note that if, after `pselect()` returns successfully, you do a lot of work, you may experience bigger latency when responding to `SIGTERM` (since the process must do all processing and return to `pselect()` before actually processing the signal). If this is a problem, you must use a flag variable inside the signal handler, so that you can check for this variable in a number of specific points in your code. Using a flag variable does not eliminate the race condition and does not eliminate the need for `pselect()`, though.

**Remember:** whenever you need to wait on some file descriptors *or* for the delivery of a signal, you *must* use `pselect()` (or `ppoll()`, for the systems that support it).

**Edit:** nothing better than a code example to illustrate the usage.

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// Signal handler to catch SIGTERM.
void sigterm(int signo) {
    (void)signo;
}

int main(void) {
    // Install the signal handler for SIGTERM.
    struct sigaction s;
    s.sa_handler = sigterm;
    sigemptyset(&s.sa_mask);
    s.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGTERM, &s, NULL);

    // Block SIGTERM.
    sigset_t sigset, oldset;
    sigemptyset(&sigset);
    sigaddset(&sigset, SIGTERM);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sigset, &oldset);

    // Enter the pselect() loop, using the original mask as argument.
    fd_set set;
    FD_ZERO(&set);
    FD_SET(0, &set);
    while (pselect(1, &set, NULL, NULL, NULL, &oldset) >= 0) {
        // Do some processing. Note that the process will not be
        // interrupted while inside this loop.
        sleep(5);
    }

    // See why pselect() has failed.
    if (errno == EINTR)
        puts("Interrupted by SIGTERM.");
    else
        perror("pselect()");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: @Akek: Firstly, thanks for the thorough explanation. I have a few questions though: The SIGTERM signal can arrive at a moment where your thread is not blocked at select() -- How to handle that SIGTERM? seeking input from the fds is one of the things (not the only thing) that my process does.

Comment: @hari: If you do the above, the signal will _never_ be delivered on that condition. If it arrives outside `pselect()`, the signal is deferred and delivered only in the moment you call `pselect()`. Also, there is nothing bad in deferring the signal for later processing. If you want to handle the signal as instantly as possible, you will have to use the flag approach I've described briefly. And instead of just setting a flag, you actually can do more processing in the signal handler, but it's dangerous: you're limited to call async-safe functions only, and the global state might be inconsistent.

Comment: Thanks. BTW, at some point in time, I do need to `SIG_UNBLOCK` the blocked signals too, right?

Comment: The above example is complete (in regards to `SIGTERM`). If you unblock `SIGTERM` somewhere, you risk receiving the signal outside `pselect()`. If you use the flag approach, `SIGTERM` will remain _unblocked_, and will be blocked only right before checking for the flag and calling `pselect()`, and will be unblocked after `pselect()` returns. All other signals are untouched.

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me. In my program, there is a function which does all the `read` on `pipe`. So where should I put all this code? In `main()` or in that function which does read on pipe?

Comment: That's up to how your program is structured. If it is small or simple enough, I'd follow the template on the example: put the signal management calls and the `pselect()` loop right in `main()`, and call a do-all-work function inside the loop (replacing the `sleep()` call); in your case, the function that `read()`s. This function will never be interrupted by `SIGTERM`.

Comment: @hari let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2175/discussion-between-alek-and-hari)

Answer (score 4):

The answer is partly in one of the comment in the Q&A you point to;

*>  Interrupt will cause select() to return a -1 with errno set to EINTR*

That is; for any interrupt(signal) caught the select will return, and the errno will be set to EINTR.

Now if you specifically want to catch SIGTERM, then you need to set that up with a call to `signal`, like this;

```
signal(SIGTERM,yourcatchfunction);
```

where your catch function should be defined something like

```
void yourcatchfunction(int signaleNumber) { .... }
```

So in summary, you have setup a signal handler `yourcatchfunction` and your program is currently in a `select()` call waiting for IO -- when a signal arrives, your catchfunction will be called and when you return from that the select call will return with the errno set to EINTR.

However be aware that the SIGTERM can occur *at any time* so you may **not** be in the select call when it occur, in which case you will never see the EINTR but only a regular call of the `yourcatchfunction`

Hence the select() returning with err and errno EINTR is just so you can take non-blocking action -- it is not what will catch the signal.

Comment: Good point, Soren -- On re-reading, the OP is asking how to catch a signal.  The signal catching has to be set up prior to the signal arriving at the process, prior to the select() call.

Comment: @Soren: Thank you. Where in the code should I put `signal(SIGTERM,yourcatchfunction);` ??

Comment: In most cases you should put the call to `signal()` as part of you initialization of the process.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `select()` in a loop.  This is known as restarting the system call.  Here is some pseudo-C.

```
int retval = -1;
int select_errno = 0;

do {
   retval = select(...);

   if (retval < 0)
   {
       /* Cache the value of errno in case a system call is later
        * added prior to the loop guard (i.e., the while expression). */
       select_errno = errno;
   }

   /* Other system calls might be added here.  These could change the
    * value of errno, losing track of the error during the select(),
    * again this is the reason we cached the value.  (E.g, you might call
    * a log method which calls gettimeofday().) */

/* Automatically restart the system call if it was interrupted by
 * a signal -- with a while loop. */
} while ((retval < 0) && (select_errno == EINTR));

if (retval < 0) {
   /* Handle other errors here. See select man page. */
} else {
   /* Successful invocation of select(). */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have a question: what do you mean by the comment "Automatically restart the ...."

Comment: The signal ostensibly interrupted the call to ``select()`` before it had a chance to return back to the caller (you). In this case (if ``errno`` is set to ``EINTR``) you just go back into the loop and call ``select`` again thereby "restarting" the call.

Comment: @unluddite: Thanks, I am trying to understand the `do while()` condition combination: when both the sub-conditions are true, that means, `select()` returned because of a signal, correct? but if `retval is not < 0` and `select_errno == EINTR` that means some other call (other than `select()`) got interrupted?

Comment: No, if ``select_errno == EINTR`` then ``retval`` **must** be ``< 0`` (-1, in fact). A -1 as the return means that "something other than the norm" happened. We check the value of ``errno`` and if its set to ``EINTR`` then that "something" was a signal that interrupted the call.

Comment: @hari - unluddite is correct because I initialized ```select_errno``` to ```0```, which does not equal ```EINTR```.  If I had not initialized the variable, there would be a small probability of accidentally having that value.  Otherwise, ```select_errno``` is never assigned another value than ```0``` except when ```retval < 0```.

Comment: May I suggest you not call this technique "restarting the system call"?  That phrase is easily (mis)understood as the semantics of SA_RESTART and some historical `signal()` implementations, both quite germane to a discussion of signals and system calls.