# Waiting for long running ioctl on a non-blocking file descriptor

Tags: c++, c, linux, serial-port

Take a serial port. A serial port can call `ioctl` with `TIOCMIWAIT` to wait for a signal change. However if the serial port is open as non-blocking, how does one use something like `select`, `poll` or `epoll` to break out of an event-loop when a signal line like CTS changes? Lets assume that the serial port is also used heavily for reading and writing. Spawning another thread seems like a bad option.

On Windows, `OVERLAPPED` IO solves this problem perfectly.

I am interested in the specific case listed above but also how to approach writing device drivers that need to pass an interrupt to user space.

Comment: As far as I can tell, such a mechanism does not exist. I have spent quite a while looking for one. I'm on the verge of designing and documenting a `TIOCMNOTIFY` call which registers interest for later notification via `poll`() et.al. Though I've no idea how to argue that into Linux kernel... :/

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to look at using pselect(). It's the same as select() but it also allows you to set a signal mask. An example of how to use pselect can be found in the top answer here:

[catching signals while reading from pipe with select()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962150/catching-signals-while-reading-from-pipe-with-select)

Comment: Does not really help since what signal will be generated by the ioctl?