# How my signal handler is called if a signal occurs during pselect?

Tags: c, unix, signals, signal-handling

I have a doubt on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962150/catching-signals-while-reading-from-pipe-with-select): how the signal handler sigterm is called during pselect syscall?

Comment: In the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6962573/2505965), `pselect` atomically re-installs the original signal mask, thus *unblocking* the delivery of `SIGTERM` for its duration. The Linux manual for [`pselect(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/pselect) has a clear description of this behaviour. This does not mean the signal handler *is* called, necessarily, just that it *can be* (in which case `pselect` would also be interrupted).

Comment: @Oka how can I force the signal handler to be called?

Comment: You signal the process: [`kill(1)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1.html), [`kill(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html), [`raise(3)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/raise.3.html), etc. Read [`signal(7)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) for an overview.

Comment: Note that, as is, this question relies too much on the [linked content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6962150/2505965) to give it context, and does not exactly stand on its own as a complete (or overly clear) topic. Please try to elaborate on your issue, with examples where possible, for a better chance at a complete answer.